# How can I write a extension function to instantiate a AndroidViewModel in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack

Somebody wrote two extension function (Code A2) for both `Fragment` and `FragmentActivity` to  instantiate a `ViewModel`, it works well, you can see Code A1 and Code A3.

I hope to write two extension function (Code B2) for both `Fragment` and `FragmentActivity` to  instantiate a `AndroidViewModel`, you can see Code B1 and Code B3, how can I do? Thanks!

**Code A1**

```
class HomeViewModel_A(private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) :  ViewModel() {

}
```

**Code A2**

```
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> Fragment.getViewModel(noinline creator: (() -> T)? = null): T {
    return if (creator == null)
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(T::class.java)
    else
        ViewModelProvider(this, BaseViewModelFactory(creator)).get(T::class.java)
}

inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> FragmentActivity.getViewModel(noinline creator: (() -> T)? = null): T {
    return if (creator == null)
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(T::class.java)
    else
        ViewModelProvider(this, BaseViewModelFactory(creator)).get(T::class.java)
}
```

**Code A3**

```
class FragmentHome : Fragment() {
    private val mHomeViewModel_A by lazy {
        getViewModel {
            HomeViewModel_A(provideRepository(mContext))
        }
    }

}
```

**Code B1**

```
class HomeViewModel_B(application: Application,private val mDBVoiceRepository: DBVoiceRepository) :  AndroidViewModel(application)  {

}
```

**Code B2**

```
?
```

**Code B3**

```
class FragmentHome : Fragment() {
  private val mHomeViewModel_B by lazy {     
       ?      
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you know the androidx Ktx library already has functions for this? No need to recreate them.

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me sample code ?

Comment: BTW, the viewModel `HomeViewModel_A` need to pass paramters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ktx Fragments library already has a function for concisely creating a lazy delegate to retrieve a view model: `Fragment.viewModels()` and `FragmentActivity.viewModels()`.

These work for both ViewModel and AndroidViewModels with the default constructors (empty, or an Application parameter respectively), or you can use the trailing lambda to return a view model factory. You would use it like this:

```
class FragmentHome : Fragment() {
  private val mHomeViewModel_B: MyViewModel by viewModels()
}
```

or

```
class FragmentHome : Fragment() {
  private val mHomeViewModel_B: MyViewModel by viewModels { getMyViewModelFactory() }
}
```

To get something equivalent to what you have in **A2**, you can wrap this function to have it build a factory for you:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> Fragment.viewModelFactory(crossinline creator: () -> VM): Lazy<VM> {
    return viewModels {
        object : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
            override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
                return creator() as T
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  `private val mHomeViewModel_B by viewModels()` maybe should be `private val mHomeViewModel_B: HomeViewModel_B by viewModels()`

Comment: And more, your code  `...Fragment.viewModelFactory...`  can't be compiled, could you write a full code for   instantiate ViewMode who require parameters?

Comment: OK, I've fixed it. I was going off memory before. The `Factory` class can't be converted from a lambda like I had it because its functional signature has a generic type.

Answer (score 1):

### Fragment Ktx

`by viewModels(...)` is part of [fragment-ktx](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx#fragment) library, it's a convienience short hand for creating a `lazy` delegate obtaining `ViewModels`.

```
// creates lazy delegate for obtaining zero-argument MyViewModel
private val viewModel : MyViewModel by viewModels()
// it's functionally equal to:
private val viewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
}

// with factory:
private val viewModel : MyViewModel by viewModels { BaseViewModelFactory {  } }
// is equal to:
private val viewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(this, BaseViewModelFactory {  }).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
}

class BaseViewModelFactory(val creator: () -> ViewModel) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return creator() as T
    }
}
```